# A genuine HTML cross-browser conundrum?

Tags: html, css, html-entities

This is... odd. Given the following HTML code:

```html
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;">Arrow in Arial, 11pt, bold: &rarr;</span><br />
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:11pt;">Arrow in Arial, 11pt, not bold: &rarr;</span><br />
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;">Arrow in Arial, 12pt, bold: &rarr;</span><br />
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12pt;">Arrow in Arial, 12pt, not bold: &rarr;</span><br />
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:13pt;font-weight:bold;">Arrow in Arial, 13pt, bold: &rarr;</span><br />
    <span style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:13pt;">Arrow in Arial, 13pt, not bold: &rarr;</span><br />
```

What would you expect to see? I know what I expected. But in my test environment (Windows 7, every browser I tried [Chrome, Opera, Firefox and IE]) I see this:

[image]

Notice that strange third arrow? Since it occurs in every browser I tried (on Windows), I was thinking perhaps it was attributable to something like ClearType®, but I turned that off and still see the same thing. And if I change the 12pt bold to 12.5pt bold, the arrow's tail reappears.

It's been a long night and I'm sleepy, so perhaps I've missed something obvious?

Comment: Shows normal for me. Most likely some kind of rounding/ sub-pixel rendering issue though I would assume. Might depend on a multitude of factors. Does anything change about this when you (slowly) scroll the window content? What happens when you copy&paste the output from the browser into Word/OpenOffice for example?

Comment: It shows correctly on Macs. I should mention also that this was brought to my attention by users, so it's not just my dev machine. I haven't looked at other symbols yet. Paste into Word looks fine at first, but when I zoom in or out, I see (at various points) some arrows LOSE or GAIN their tails. So yes, definitely a Windows render issue, and not limited to browsers. But it is somewhat critical for the chemistry/math-centric stuff this application is displaying, because an arrow can now - without warning - look more like a greater-than symbol on the screen, which is a definite problem.